# Animate in python displays a stationary graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

We've been trying to animate a graph  for parameters in a water tank along various time intervals. It plots without errors but does not animate with time.

Code for the animation is below:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

T= [0*60,5*60,8*60,10*60,12*60]     #minutes                                   #Time correspondeing to I (inflow) below. The (*60) is to convert the time from hours to minutes
I= [0.08,0.06,0.05,0.00,0.00]       #cubic meter/sec                           #Inflow values corresponding to the above T (time)
h0= 11.0     #meters                                                           #Initial water head value
dt= 10.0     #minutes                                                          #time step 
k= 0.01*60   #sqm/min                                                          #Flow coefficient  
R= 8.0       #meters                                                           #Sphere radius 
Tmax= 12.0*60       #minutes                                                   #Total estimation time 
n= int(Tmax/dt)+1                 


ts = np.linspace(0,10,101)
h_th=[h0]
t_th=[0]
Area_th= [np.pi*(R**2 - (abs(R - h0))**2)]
Q_th= [k*np.sqrt(h0)]
inflow_th=[I[0]*60]

for i in range (1,n):                                                          #looping through the steps
    t_th.append(i*dt)
    h_th.append(h_th[i-1]+(dt*(inflow_th[i-1]-Q_th[i-1]))/(Area_th[i-1]))
    Area_th.append(np.pi*(R**2 - (abs(R - h_th[i]))**2))
    Q_th.append(k*(np.sqrt(h_th[i])))
    inflow_th.append((np.interp(i*dt,T,I))*60)

fig=plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,5))

i=0
ax1=plt.subplot(4,1,1)
pl1,=plt.plot(t_th[0:i+1],h_th[0:i+1],'r-',linewidth=3,label='water level')
plt.ylabel('Head Level (m)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax1.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax2=plt.subplot(4,1,2)
pl2,=plt.plot(t_th[0:i+1],inflow_th[0:i+1]*60,'b--',linewidth=3,label='inflow')
plt.ylabel('Inflow in (m3/min)')    
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax3=plt.subplot(4,1,3)
ax3.set_xlim(ts[0], ts[100])
ax3.set_ylim(-5,5)
pl3,=plt.plot(t_th[0:i+1],Q_th[0:i+1],'g-',linewidth=3,label='outflow')
plt.ylabel('Outflow (m3/min)')
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.legend(loc='best')        
ax4=plt.subplot(4,1,4)
ax4.set_xlim(ts[0], ts[100])
pl4,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],h_th[0:i+1],'y-',linewidth=3,label='overflow')
plt.ylabel('Overflow')
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
#plt.legend(loc='best')


def myAnimation(i):
    if i<1: return [] # No need to update frame 0, we already drawn it
    pl1.set_data(t_th[0:i+1], h_th[0:i+1])
    ax1.set_xlim(t_th[0],t_th[i])
    pl2.set_data(t_th[0:i+1], inflow_th[0:i+1])
    ax2.set_xlim(ts[0],ts[i])
    ax2.set_ylim(min(inflow_th[0:i+1]), max(inflow_th[0:i+1]))
    pl3.set_data(t_th[0:i+1], Q_th[0:i+1])
    pl4.set_data(t_th[0:i+1], h_th[0:i+1])
    ax4.set_ylim(min(h_th[0:i+1]), max(h_th[0:i+1]))
    return [pl1, pl2, pl3, pl4]


theAnim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, myAnimation, frames=100, interval=100, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Time intervals have been redefined and even the pause intervals. Everything works except the animation.

Comment: Why the double indentation. And what is `i`? `h`? `inflow`? `Q`? `h_th`? Isn't there any missing code here? Like a for loop or something?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14pwse-8DbgTAD4NRRPWhr8MfC2YwViaX/view?usp=share_link   

here is the entire code

Comment: That is too big. What we need is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that contains all that is needed to see the problem (including `i`, `h`,... if they are needed), but only what is needed (we don't really care about water level here. Even 4 figures are probably 3 too many, since you problem seems to be only about animation).

Comment: I have updated the code in the question above to be more concise.

Answer (score 2):

### Minimal example

So, for example here is a minimal reproducible example, made to look as much as possible as your code.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = np.linspace(0,10,101)
h=np.sin(ts)
inflow=np.cos(ts)
Q=np.tan(ts)
h_th=np.exp(ts)

plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,5))
plt.ion()
plt.show()

for i in range(100):
    plt.clf()
    plt.subplot(4,1,1)
    plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],h[0:i+1],'r-',linewidth=3,label='water level')
    plt.ylabel('Head Level (m)')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.subplot(4,1,2)
    plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],inflow[0:i+1]*60,'b--',linewidth=3,label='inflow')
    plt.ylabel('Inflow in (m3/min)')    
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.subplot(4,1,3)
    plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],Q[0:i+1],'g-',linewidth=3,label='outflow')
    plt.ylabel('Outflow (m3/min)')
    plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
    plt.legend(loc='best')        
    plt.subplot(4,1,4)
    plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],h_th[0:i+1],'y-',linewidth=3,label='overflow')
    plt.ylabel('Overflow')
    plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    #plt.legend(loc='best') # I don't think you need it twice
    plt.pause(0.1) # Reduced to 0.1, because I am not patient.
    # plt.show() #Not really needed, but works also with it
```

Note that, as is, it works on my computer. The only difference with your code (except slight changes commented, but that change nothing to the animation working or not; and, of course, the creation of a minimal example, but I assume that your full code contains what needed to compute `Q`, `inflow`, ..., and that, somehow, you iterate `i`, otherwise you wouldn't expect any animation. Hard to be sure, since even your full code contains nothing of that sort, only a static plot, and some commented partial attempt to animate it, with the same problem I've already mentioned, for example, no definition of `i`), the only other difference with your code, so, is that I uncommented initial `plt.ion()` and `plt.show()`. But I assume that, since you typed that code (and commented it), you had already tried that.

But well, my minimal example does produce an animation.

### Update data

Now, that is not yet the correct way to do it.
Because here, you are rebuilding the whole plot at each iteration. Including legends, labels, etc. That's too heavy.

What you should do, is plot things only once. And then update the data only.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = np.linspace(0,10,101)
h=np.sin(ts)
inflow=np.cos(ts)
Q=np.tan(ts)
h_th=np.exp(ts)

plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,5))
plt.ion()
plt.show()

i=0
plt.clf()
ax1=plt.subplot(4,1,1)
pl1,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],h[0:i+1],'r-',linewidth=3,label='water level')
plt.ylabel('Head Level (m)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax1.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax2=plt.subplot(4,1,2)
pl2,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],inflow[0:i+1]*60,'b--',linewidth=3,label='inflow')
plt.ylabel('Inflow in (m3/min)')    
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax3=plt.subplot(4,1,3)
ax3.set_xlim(ts[0], ts[100])
ax3.set_ylim(-5,5)
pl3,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],Q[0:i+1],'g-',linewidth=3,label='outflow')
plt.ylabel('Outflow (m3/min)')
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.legend(loc='best')        
ax4=plt.subplot(4,1,4)
ax4.set_xlim(ts[0], ts[100])
pl4,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],h_th[0:i+1],'y-',linewidth=3,label='overflow')
plt.ylabel('Overflow')
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
#plt.legend(loc='best')

for i in range(100):
    pl1.set_data(ts[0:i+1], h[0:i+1])
    ax1.set_xlim(ts[0],ts[i])
    pl2.set_data(ts[0:i+1], inflow[0:i+1])
    ax2.set_xlim(ts[0],ts[i])
    ax2.set_ylim(min(inflow[0:i+1]), max(inflow[0:i+1]))
    pl3.set_data(ts[0:i+1], Q[0:i+1])
    pl4.set_data(ts[0:i+1], h_th[0:i+1])
    ax4.set_ylim(min(h_th[0:i+1]), max(h_th[0:i+1]))
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

With different styles for x and y limits (fixed or not).

The changes from before are, that I plot only once. And keep in variables two things: axes (`ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4`) that I need to call `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`. And "artist" that is the return of `plot`. That I need to update the data.

So no need to recreate the layout, legends, axis, style, subplots, ... each time. Just to update the data.

### Animation

That is also reinventing the wheel. Tho I do it from times to times. For example when I want to integrate that in another "main loop" (for a GUI or something).

There is a specific module for animation. That does the exact same thing I did. But more efficiently (updating only pixels that changed, interacting with mainloop with no need for an explicit pause, and things like that).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


ts = np.linspace(0,10,101)
h=np.sin(ts)
inflow=np.cos(ts)
Q=np.tan(ts)
h_th=np.exp(ts)

fig=plt.figure(1,figsize=(12,5))

i=0
ax1=plt.subplot(4,1,1)
pl1,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],h[0:i+1],'r-',linewidth=3,label='water level')
plt.ylabel('Head Level (m)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax1.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax2=plt.subplot(4,1,2)
pl2,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],inflow[0:i+1]*60,'b--',linewidth=3,label='inflow')
plt.ylabel('Inflow in (m3/min)')    
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax3=plt.subplot(4,1,3)
ax3.set_xlim(ts[0], ts[100])
ax3.set_ylim(-5,5)
pl3,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],Q[0:i+1],'g-',linewidth=3,label='outflow')
plt.ylabel('Outflow (m3/min)')
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.legend(loc='best')        
ax4=plt.subplot(4,1,4)
ax4.set_xlim(ts[0], ts[100])
pl4,=plt.plot(ts[0:i+1],h_th[0:i+1],'y-',linewidth=3,label='overflow')
plt.ylabel('Overflow')
plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
#plt.legend(loc='best')


def myAnimation(i):
    if i<1: return [] # No need to update frame 0, we already drawn it
    pl1.set_data(ts[0:i+1], h[0:i+1])
    ax1.set_xlim(ts[0],ts[i])
    pl2.set_data(ts[0:i+1], inflow[0:i+1])
    ax2.set_xlim(ts[0],ts[i])
    ax2.set_ylim(min(inflow[0:i+1]), max(inflow[0:i+1]))
    pl3.set_data(ts[0:i+1], Q[0:i+1])
    pl4.set_data(ts[0:i+1], h_th[0:i+1])
    ax4.set_ylim(min(h_th[0:i+1]), max(h_th[0:i+1]))
    return [pl1, pl2, pl3, pl4]


theAnim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, myAnimation, frames=100, interval=100, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Main changes here, is that I imported `animation`, kept the figure in a variable `fig`, and created a callback to update the data (the loop is `animation`'s job).
Note that that callback needs to return an array of what "artist" have changed. Here, all of them, that is `[pl1, pl2, pl3, pl4]`.

Note also that even tho I never use that variable (at least, for now), I need the save the result of `FuncAnimation` call to a variable `theAnim`. Because if I don't, garbage collector will remove that return value after a while. And that destruction will also imply destruction of the animation itself.

### Create a gif (or mp4,...)

You haven't asked this question. But failed attempts and comments in your code show that you want, once you get the animation working, the ability to save the result in movie (or gif, which I'll do in this, to be able to include the result here)

With `animation` module, that's very easy.

Just add to the very end of the code

```py
theAnim.save("anim.gif")
```

(If you keep both the `.save` and the `plt.show`, then animation will be saved to the file only after you close the drawing window. If you comment the `plt.show()` line, then no window is opened, but a file containing the animation is created)

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! However, it doesn't return any results when I use my values.